# Как распределить процессы nginx и php-fpm в kubernetes

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, kubernetes

Только начал осваиваться с kubernetes и docker-ом. Как я понял, идеология docker: один контейнер - один процесс. При этом в конфиге nginx в одноименном контейнере с docker-hub:

```
worker_processes = 1
```

а php-fpm :

```
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Должен ли я разбить все по контейнерам? Не слишком ли это затратно по ресурсам? Или лучше по одному контейнеру nginx с конкретным worker_processes ?

При этом весь траффик будет ходить через kube-proxy между нодами, а мне бы ходелось, минимизировать это, чтобы nginx-контейнер на ноде обращался к php-fpm на ней же. Можно сделать их в одном pod и ходить через localhost - правильный ли это подход?

Наверное, я чего-то не понимаю в принципах docker/kubernetes,  буду рад советам, что вообще погуглить, что бы разобраться.

Comment: паралелизация и маштабирование заложенно в идеологии кубика, зачем замарачиваться по количеству рабочиз процессов ? (если это не бд конечно)